# PHP infinite loop process; Is it good solution?

Tags: php, infinite-loop, background-process

I'm creating a plugin for a CMS and need one or more preriodical tasks in background. As it is a plugin for an open source CMS, cron job is not a perfect solution because users may not have access to cron on their server.

I'm going to start a infinite loop via an AJAX request then abort XHR request. So HTTP connection will be closed but script continue running.

Is it a good solution generally? What about server resources? Is there any shutdown or limitation policies in servers (such as Apache) for long time running threads?

Comment: Normally php got 60 seconds for running. So Cron Job are better, if not possible there are online service that will call a php page on 60 secs interval, you can use that to do a cron job system (Example)

Comment: I don't like this idea. PHP has max_execution_time. It is possible to set max_execution_time by runtime, but I really can not suggest to use that. Next, you will have limits on fastCGI and/or Apache. At least they will kill your PHP process. Same reason to avoid changing this settings, like you mention for not using cron. It really depents on what you want to in your task. Maybe it's a good idea to kick of your process by a client request (maybe n-th request) or start a script by cron periodical.

Answer (score 0):

Long running php scripts are not too good idea. If your script uses session variables your user won't be able to load any pages until the other session based script is closed.

If you really need long running scripts make sure its not using any session and keep them under the maximum execution time. Do not let it run without your control. It can cause various problems. I remember when I made such a things like that and my server just crashed several times.

Know what you want to do and make sure it's well tested on different servers.

Also search for similiar modules and check what methods they use for such a problems like that. Learn from the pros. :)

Comment: Avoid long running scripts is not a solution. Imagine one wants to run a daemon that is always there.